# May Jews listen to music during the day of a Sefer Torah burning

Tags: halacha, mourning-aveilus, music, sefer-torah, yoreh-deah

According to the [Shulchan Arukh, Yoreh De'ah 340:37](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh,_Yoreh_De%27ah.340.37)  Jews are supposed to tear Kriah after seeing a Sefer Torah being intentionally burned. However, may they listen to music the day when they  see it burnt, or does the usual prohibition against listening to  music since it brings simchah during aveilut apply here?

Comment: Why wouldn’t it?

Comment: What about all the rules of avelut? Do any apply? Tearing Kriah isn't really part of avelut per se.

Comment: What is "the usual prohibition of music during aveilut"?

Comment: A Sefer Torah was intentionally burned and someone wants to listne to music!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is based on the assumption that nowadays one may listen to music.

This is a false premise. Listening to music nowadays that music is ubiquitous is forbidden by the strict letter of the law.

The Rambam (משנה תורה, הלכות תעניות ה׳:י״ד) already ruled:

> וְכֵן גָּזְרוּ **שֶׁלֹּא לְנַגֵּן בִּכְלֵי שִׁיר**. וְכָל מִינֵי זֶמֶר וְכָל מַשְׁמִיעֵי קוֹל שֶׁל שִׁיר אָסוּר לִשְׂמֹחַ בָּהֶן **וְאָסוּר לְשָׁמְעָן מִפְּנֵי הַחֻרְבָּן**. וַאֲפִלּוּ שִׁירָה בַּפֶּה עַל הַיַּיִן אֲסוּרָה שֶׁנֶּאֱמַר (ישעיה כד ט) "בַּשִּׁיר לֹא יִשְׁתּוּ יָיִן". וּכְבָר נָהֲגוּ כָּל יִשְׂרָאֵל לוֹמַר דִּבְרֵי תֻּשְׁבָּחוֹת אוֹ שִׁיר שֶׁל הוֹדָאוֹת לָאֵל וְכַיּוֹצֵא בָּהֶן עַל הַיַּיִן:‏

The Shulchan Aruch  (אורח חיים תק״ס:ג' - לעשות זכר לחורבן) similarly mentions the ban against music, though the Remo may permit it for those who rarely listen to music:

> וכן **גזרו שלא לנגן בכלי שיר וכל מיני זמר וכל משמיעי קול של שיר** לשמח בהם:‏
> ***הגה** ויש אומרים דוקא מי שרגיל בהם כגון המלכים שעומדים ושוכבים בכלי שיר או בבית המשתה [טור]*
> ואסור לשומעם מפני החורבן ואפי' שיר בפה על היין אסורה שנא' בשיר לא ישתו יין וכבר נהגו כל ישראל לומר דברי תשבחות או שיר של הודאות וזכרון חסדי הקדוש ברוך הוא על היין:‏
> ***הגה** וכן לצורך מצוה כגון בבית חתן וכלה הכל שרי* [תוס' וסמ"ג והגהות מיימוני]:‏

That is why it's not codified whether a mourner may or may not listen to music, since nobody should be listening to music.

---

But even if listening to music would be permitted nowadays, **we have a source that would frown upon listening to music on a day of a Sefer Torah burning,** and on that anniversary henceforth.

One of the reasons we fast on 17 Tamuz is because אַפּוֹסְטוּמוּס הָרָשָׁע burnt a Sefer Torah.

So not only would music be prohibited on a day a Sefer Torah is burnt, but fasting would be appropriate. On fast days (even those who are permitted to eat) are forbidden from indulging and enjoying themselves. Even going on a stroll is disallowed. Listening to music is not mentioned, as we already discussed, because it's always frowned upon.

(Actually, the Kitzur Shulchan Aruch in 122:1 explicitly forbids music on 17 Tammuz, even if one makes a living as a musician for non-Jews.)